# Nested functions in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a method that used is inside method, each one is working well independently but when one used inside one an error occurs

```
  function [cov]=CC(a,b)

      meana=mean(a);
      meanb=mean(b);
      entity=0;

      for k=1:10
          entity=entity+((a(1,k)-meana) * (b(1,k)-meanb));
      end

      cov=entity;
```

works fine but if used inside this method some error occur that says

> ??? Attempted to access b(1,10); index out of bounds because size(b)=[1,9].
>       Error in ==> CC at 9
>             `entity=entity+((a(1,k)-meana) * (b(1,k)-meanb));`
>       Error in ==> CM at 8
>       `e=CC(dim(1,i:10),dim(1,j:10));`

The function `CM` is shown below

```
function [covM]=CM(a,b)

    dim=[a b];

    for i=1:2
        for j=1:2
            e=CC(dim(1,i:10),dim(1,j:10));
        end
    end

   covM=e;
```

So what does this statement `" ??? Attempted to access b(10); index out of bounds because numel(b)=9 "`
mean? `b` is `[1,10]` not `[1,9]`

Comment: the error is explicit. b is a [1,9] vector. therefore access the index 10 is not possible.

Comment: Moreover, the error occurs because you're cutting down the size of the dim array in the `CC(dim(...` line by using the loop index

Answer (score 0):

The original variable 'b' is 1x10, but in the line:

```
e=CC(dim(1,i:10),dim(1,j:10));
```

you actually call the function CC, that gets two variables, and treat them again as `a`, `b`, but now they are different :

`dim(1,i:10)` now (inside `CC`) called `a`

`dim(1,j:10)` now (inside `CC`) called `b`.

Because of the loop, when j=2, then `dim(1,j:10)` is 1x9, and so variable `b` that inside `CC` function. this is the reason for the error.